# How to access childern of a model in a query set django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have a model for Products and a model for categories:
Each product can have multiple categories and each category can have multiple sub categories
for example:

categories:

```
-Digital devices:
    -laptop
    -smartphone
    -PC
```

products:

```
Mylaptop1
    -category=laptop
Myphone2
    -category=smartphone
```

i want to filter products using parent category for example when user reach this address : mysite.com/products/digital-devices i want to show both Mylaptop1 and Myphone2.
I dont have problem with filtering sub categories but how can i filter using parent category in query set.

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True, 
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name="children")

class Product(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True),
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, allow_unicode=True),
    description=models.TextField(blank=True),  
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
```

views.py

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
category = None
categories = Category.objects.all()
products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
photos = ProductImage.objects.all()

if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_slug)

    products = products.filter(category=category) # query for sub categories
    products = products.filter(category__in=[category.children.all]) # i tried to use this query set to get products using parent category but it does not work
```

So how can i access to the products that have children categories using parent category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter sub-category via field `parent`

```
parent_category = Category.objects.get(slug='DigitalDevices')    
products = products.filter(
    category__in=Category.objects.filter(parent=parent_category)
)
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you